# PowerShell cmdlet not finding NuGet assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-core

I created a C# class library that will host a number of PowerShell Core (6.1.2) Cmdlets.

The project includes two NuGet packages:

- System.Management.Automation (for Core) (6.1.2)
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (2.18.3)

The `New-Session` Cmdlet:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation; 
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client; 
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace PsOracleCore.Cmdlets
{
  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "Session")]
  [OutputType(typeof(OracleConnection))] 
  public class NewSessionCmdlet : Cmdlet 
  {
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
    public string Account { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty] 
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Position = 2)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty] 
    public string DataSource { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
      string connectionString = String.Format("User Id={0};Password={1};Data Source={2};",this.Account,this.Password,this.DataSource);

      OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
      connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; connection.Open();
      WriteObject(connection);
    }

  } // class
} // namespace
```

The xUnit tests (that include a reference to the project) work as expected.

After importing the module into a `pwsh` session (on OS X), I attempt to use the Cmdlet:

```
$ pwsh
PowerShell 6.1.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS [project]/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1> import-module PsOracleCore
PS [project]/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1> new-session
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=2.0.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-session
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

I was able to eliminate the error by creating a symlink to the assembly in the project's `/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1` directory:

```
$ ln -s ~/.nuget/packages/oracle.manageddataaccess.core/2.18.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

Is there something missing from my project?

If I want to distribute the Cmdlet's assembly, what will I need to do to ensure that the NuGet package is properly installed and referenced?

Comment: What does your module folder look like on disk?  I only work on Windows (using the Framework, not Core), but when I build and deploy, the module folder includes my DLL, the DLL-Help.xml file (if you aren't using RedGate's XmlDoc2CmdletDoc package, take a look at it) and all of the NuGetted stuff that the C# code uses.  The NuGet-ted DLLs don't get "installed", they just get copied to the output bin folder (and then to the module folder)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to my project's `.csproj` file.

The results:

[image]

Questions:

- Can selected assemblies be marked for copylocal, rather than all of them?  Given that this assembly is reference via PowerShell, the `System.*` ones seem unnecessary.
- Shouldn't NuGet handle the installation of dependencies when my assembly is used, negating the need to distribute the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` assembly manually?